# "This is one of the most important lessons I've learned" – Present Simple with Present Perfect?

Tags: sentence-construction, present-perfect, present-simple

Let's say you are describing your professor back when you were in college.

> His sustained commitment to learning, while never forgetting how to loosen up a bit or de-stress, **is** one of the most important lessons **I have learned** from him.

(Re-constructed, sentence #2)

> ''His sustained commitment to learning, while never forgetting how to loosen up a bit or de-stress, **is** a lesson **I have learned** from him.

- First, there is the Past Tense followed by the last clause which is expressing my opinion in the Present i.e. NOW.

Maybe this is the best form... I think

P.S: I know how present perfect tense works but not quite, specifically this case. As you can see there is the word ''**is**'' but I am not sure if it is grammatical. Please, shed some light.

Comment: Seems like the "but never forget how to loosen up a bit or de-stress" needs editing

Comment: Your sentence is not grammatical.  **but never forget** is wrong. You would need to say something like **while never forgetting how...**.

Comment: He kept  up his commitment to learning but never forgot how to loosen up a bit and this was etc.....a phrasal verb + possessive makes it work. That said, I think you've asked this question many times in different forms.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, I am editing it.

Comment: @Lambie, I don't think so, some correlations between these two certainly, but never in this way that I am expressing my opinion in the last clause(yes! that's the word I was missing in the above question)

Comment: @John Arvin: It is still ungrammatical. **while never forgot** is wrong.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo, ok, so it's should be parallel. Got it.

Comment: How odd, my comment seems to have disappeared yet the OP is addressing me. Go figure. :)

Comment: Is my sentence ok now?

Comment: Not really. **None of this makes sense**. @Lambie, if he asked this question many times before, do you understand what it's talking about? He has an initial grammatical sentence with two verbs bolded; he has a 're-constructed' sentence with the same two verbs bolded, both verbs labelled with the wrong tenses, and with bad grammar that was apparently in the original sentence; all of this is followed by 'shed some light' please.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Do either of you guys know what the second sentence is supposed to be doing? or what the crux of the question is supposed to be? It seemed to ask about whether the past present should be joined with the present or past in the other clause... but then the second sentence is still in the present tense.

Comment: Hello, so the first sentence is FINALLY grammatical? Regarding the second sentence, I took it from Colin Fine's idea, and I'm saying this in past event+ the last clause as my opinion in PRESENT tense...

Comment: It's awkward but mostly grammatical. You're still talking about a past tense that isn't there, and I don't see how the second sentence is supposed to be distinguished from the first. Just because you go from 'one of the most...' to 'a lesson'? That difference has nothing to do with the rest of what you seem to be talking about.

Comment: This is just an analogy of that, let's say a **movie star** is being interviewed, the movie star is telling the past actions that happened during the shoot, and then he/she makes some comments about the actions, comments which are in present tense. Ok?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you wished to imply that you are still in contact with this professor, then the present perfect would do.  But if the actual relationship ended perhaps many years ago or the learning of that particular lesson occurred in the past, the simple past would be preferable.

> His commitment to learning, sustained while never forgetting to loosen up or de-stress a bit, is one of the most important lessons I **learned** from him.

P.S.
The past tense tells us ***when*** you learned this lesson from him: in the past (back when you were in college and he was your professor).

The present perfect tells us  ***that*** you have learned this lesson from him and no more. Perhaps you did not learn the lesson back in college. It might have taken some years for it to "sink in".  Perhaps you did learn it back then. The present perfect is silent with respect to when the lesson was learned. All we know is that it has been learned.

And this combination would be ungrammatical:

> One of the most important lessons I have learned from him back when I
>   was his student ...

because we cannot combine the present perfect with a time reference that excludes the present, and "back when I was his student" excludes the present.

Comment: The past doesn't require that the lesson was learned while at school. The distinction between the past and present perfect, as you said, is solely whether some learning from his example continues at present or is entirely completed. 'Learned'/'learnt' is still more correct *even if* the lesson was not fully grokked until fairly recently but is now entirely grokked.

Comment: @Ily: It is not about "requiring" anything.  Tenses are *expressive*.  The past expresses *when*.  The present perfect, *that*.  The phrase *entirely completed* begs the question in the case of learning, which is both the process which terminates and the lesson learned which remains.

Comment: That's not what 'beg the question' means, and the 'lesson learned' isn't a process and cannot be completed. You're just mixing in an entirely unrelated sense (and part of speech) of the word.

Answer (score 6):

*X is one of the most important lessons I have learned from him* is perfectly grammatical.

It (timelessly) **is** a lesson, and you (past with present relevance, therefore perfect) **have learned** it.

Comment: Yes, but the x in this case requires fixin'.

Comment: Strike a blow for UK orthography! *(you have **learnt** it)*. It's one of the relatively rare cases where our spelling reflects the spoken form better than Websterised US English! (For *most* native speakers in most contexts, I think.)

Comment: I wouldn't call it "perfectly" grammatical given the scenario: "you are describing your professor back when you were in college"

Comment: Guys, I have just edited it, is it better to make it in present tense instead of present perfect?

Comment: @John Arvin: Please see the P.S. in my answer.

Comment: @FumbleFingers 'learned' is just the **modern** orthography. ['Learnt' appears in American English](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=learned%2Clearnt&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clearned%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clearnt%3B%2Cc0) but ['learned' is still the much more common form in British English as well](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=learned%2Clearnt&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Clearned%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Clearnt%3B%2Cc0).

Comment: As with @Tᴚoɯɐuo, it's not *perfectly* grammatical. The learning from him is entirely completed, not ongoing; it's more accurate to say *that I learned* or *learnt from him*.

Comment: @lly : In Colin's defense, the sentence he gives and his explanation of it is valid. I was just bringing in OP's stated scenario since he seems to want to describe something that happened in the past, though it isn't really clear precisely what he would like to say.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yeah, the question very much still needs to be cleaned up. That said, given that the lessons provided by the college prof are assumed to be entirely finished and now fully understood, the present perfect really isn't the best way to go about it, as your answer says. There isn't a present relevance if the learning isn't still ongoing.

Comment: @Ily: That's not quite the distinction I would make.  As Colin says, a lesson learned remains a lesson learned, and therefore it can always have present relevance as the lesson learned stays with you.  The distinction is whether OP wants to say *when* he learned the lesson or *that* he has learned a lesson.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo It isn't, as you'd see if you considered the case of the professor being dead. 'Have learned' would be entirely inappropriate, regardless of the *when*/*that* distinction you think could be going on.

Comment: "X[his sustained commitment]  is one of the most important lessons I have learned from him" perfectly grammatical" is right.Compare: "X is one of the most important lessons I learned [or learnt] from him **this year**." Where's the problem? base form: learn, past participle and simple past: learnt or learned: both are right.

Comment: I don't get it why **lly** keeps on complaining everybody's answer, whereas, you should state the correct answer here.